# How to copy s3 objects into EKS pods directly

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-s3, amazon-eks

I am working on Kubernetes pods and I have some pods running on an application. Now, I want to copy some files inside my pods but the situation here is my files present in my s3 bucket. So, I want to know an automated way that can directly copy my s3 files into my pod's folder directory. I don't know how to do this.

If anyone knows it then please reply.

Thanks

Comment: Does the node have permissions to copy files from s3? I think the pod should have same permissions of the parent node..

Comment: @Riz It's not about the permission issue. The issue is I don't know the way to do this activity. SO, If you know How to perform this then please answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, few of them are:

1. **Using Kubectl** (very basic not automated method):  first need to download s3 files on local and copy them into application pods can use kubectl command line to perform copy operation from host fs to pod fs.

```bash
kubectl cp <local-file> <pod-name>:<file-path>
```

2. **Using Init-Container** (Automated): Write a small script to download files from s3/cloud provider and place into shared volume between init-container and main container. In that way whenever your pod is spin up, the init-container will prepare volume before running actual container.

Sample Pod yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
 - name: myapp-container
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /tmp
      name: data
  initContainers:
 - name: init-downloader
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', "aws s3 cp s3://xyz/ /tmp"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /tmp
      name: data
  volumes:
 - emptyDir: {}
    name: data
```

3. **Using CrobJob** (Periodically Update): If the data needs to be updated in volume on periodic basis and not depends on pod restarts, then additional utility can be utilised to perform this action.

- Either a script to download on local and perform kubectl copy operation on all pods
- Use other opensource project to fullfill that, for example

  - https://github.com/maorfr/skbn, Skbn is a tool for copying files and directories between Kubernetes and cloud storage providers

Sample Job Yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  labels:
    app: skbn
  name: skbn
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: skbn
    annotations:
      iam.amazonaws.com/role: skbn 
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: skbn
      containers:
      - name: skbn
        image: maorfr/skbn
        command: ["skbn"]
        args:
        - cp
        - --src
        - k8s://namespace/pod/container/path/to/copy/from
        - --dst
        - s3://bucket/path/to/copy/to
        env:
        - name: AWS_REGION
          value: us-east-1
```

There can be multiple ways to implement this requirement but mostly it will be using above mentioned methods only.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please tell that Do I need to provide aws creds because I am getting access denied error and how can we set a specific period to execute this job file again?

Comment: @PiyushMittal Yes you need to provide AWS creds, if its eks then you can use IRSA else provide AWS Env vars. To run this job periodic check CronJob (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/)

Comment: @PiyushMittal If that works for you, please upvote or accept as answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **init container** & **cronjobs** with AWS CLI to copy the files to S3 bucket.

To add further you can also use the **Volume mount** with datshim it's nice option :

```
apiVersion: com.ie.ibm.hpsys/v1alpha1
kind: Dataset
metadata:
  name: example-dataset
spec:
  local:
    type: "COS"
    accessKeyID: "{AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
    secretAccessKey: "{AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
    endpoint: "{S3_SERVICE_URL}"
    bucket: "{BUCKET_NAME}"
    readonly: "true" #OPTIONAL, default is false  
    region: "" #OPTIONAL
```

https://github.com/datashim-io/datashim

If you are looking for something with FUSE you should also checkout the https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse

Comment: CSI for S3 based on GeeseFS is https://github.com/yandex-cloud/k8s-csi-s3